# Focal Loss U-net. TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am writing a code for deeplearning and I am currently trying to implement Focal Loss in my code, as my model isnt able to train itself in its current state. I am using a GPU. Whenever I run the code, I get the TypeError stated in the title. I have installed the focal loss package and am trying to implement it in my code with:

```
from focal_loss import BinaryFocalLoss
```

When I try to run my U-net and have my model train itself while using FocalLoss, I keep getting the error stated earlier. My U-net code is as follows:

```
class UNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_classes=1, in_ch=1):
        super().__init__()

        # list of layers in encoder-decoder with number of filters
        c = [16, 32, 64, 128]

        # first conv layer that receives the image
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            conv3x3_bn(in_ch, c[0]), 
            conv3x3_bn(c[0], c[0]),
        )
        # encoder layers
        self.conv2 = encoder_conv(c[0], c[1])
        self.conv3 = encoder_conv(c[1], c[2])
        self.conv4 = encoder_conv(c[2], c[3])

        # decoder layers
        self.deconv1 = deconv(c[3],c[2])
        self.deconv2 = deconv(c[2],c[1])
        self.deconv3 = deconv(c[1],c[0])

        # last layer conv that gives us the mask
        self.out = torch.nn.Conv2d(c[0], n_classes, 3, padding=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # encoder
        x1 = self.conv1(x)
        x2 = self.conv2(x1)
        x3 = self.conv3(x2)
        x = self.conv4(x3)
        # decoder
        x = self.deconv1(x, x3)
        x = self.deconv2(x, x2)
        x = self.deconv3(x, x1)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x
    
def conv3x3_bn(ci, co):
    return torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Conv2d(ci, co, 3, padding=1),
        torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(co),
        torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    )

def encoder_conv(ci, co):
    return torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2),
        conv3x3_bn(ci, co),
        conv3x3_bn(co, co),
    )

class deconv(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ci, co):
        super(deconv, self).__init__()
        self.upsample = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(ci, co, 2, stride=2)
        self.conv1 = conv3x3_bn(ci, co)
        self.conv2 = conv3x3_bn(co, co)

    # receives the output of the previous layer and the output of the stage
    # corresponding encoder
    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.upsample(x1)
        diffX = x2.size()[2] - x1.size()[2]
        diffY = x2.size()[3] - x1.size()[3]
        x1 = F.pad(x1, (diffX, 0, diffY, 0))
        # we concatenate the tensors
        x = torch.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        return x
```

My DataSet class is as follows:

```
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y, n_classes=1):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.n_classes = n_classes

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, ix):
        img = nib.load(self.X[ix]).get_data()
        mask = nib.load(self.y[ix]).get_data()
        mask[mask==2] = 0
        img = torch.tensor(img).unsqueeze(0) 
        #mask = (np.arange(self.n_classes) == mask[...,None]).astype(np.float32) 
        #return img, torch.from_numpy(mask).permute(2,0,1)
        mask = torch.tensor(np.uint8(mask)).unsqueeze(0)
        return img, mask
```

The training model is as follows:

```
from tqdm import tqdm #allows us to output a smart progress bar

def fit(model, dataloader, epochs=50, lr=3e-4):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    criterion = BinaryFocalLoss(gamma=2) #loss
    #criterion = WeightedFocalLoss()
    model.to(device) #move model to device, which is the GPU
    hist = {'loss': [], 'iou': [], 'evaluation_loss': [], 'evaluation_iou': []}
    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
        bar = tqdm(dataloader['train']) #creates a smart progress bar for train data
        train_loss, train_iou = [], [] #create empty lists that are to be filled
        model.train()
        for imgs, masks in bar: #training the model
            imgs, masks = imgs.float().to(device), masks.float().to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            y_hat = model(imgs)
            y_hat = (y_hat - torch.min(y_hat))/(torch.max(y_hat) - torch.min(y_hat))
            #print(y_hat.shape, masks.shape, y_hat.type(), masks.type(), np.unique(y_hat.detach().cpu().numpy()), np.unique(masks.detach().cpu().numpy()))
            #print(y_hat.device, masks.device)
            #plt.imshow(np.unique(masks.cpu().numpy(), return_counts=True))
            loss = criterion(y_hat, masks)
            print('a lot of attributes')
            loss.backward()    #GRADIENT DECENT, adam optimizer
            optimizer.step()   #updating model with the new gradients
            ious = iou(y_hat, masks)
            train_loss.append(loss.item())
            train_iou.append(ious)
            bar.set_description(f"loss {np.mean(train_loss):.5f} iou {np.mean(train_iou):.5f}")
        hist['loss'].append(np.mean(train_loss))
        hist['iou'].append(np.mean(train_iou))
        bar = tqdm(dataloader['evaluation']) #creates a smart progress bar for evaluation data
        evaluation_loss, evaluation_iou = [], [] #create empty lists for evaluation loss and iou
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad(): #evaluate the model
            for imgs, masks in bar:
                imgs, masks = imgs.float().to(device), masks.float().to(device)
                y_hat = model(imgs)
                y_hat = (y_hat - torch.min(y_hat))/(torch.max(y_hat) - torch.min(y_hat))
                loss = criterion(y_hat, masks)
                ious = iou(y_hat, masks)
                evaluation_loss.append(loss.item())
                evaluation_iou.append(ious)
                bar.set_description(f"evaluation_loss {np.mean(evaluation_loss):.5f} evaluation_iou {np.mean(evaluation_iou):.5f}")
        hist['evaluation_loss'].append(np.mean(evaluation_loss))
        hist['evaluation_iou'].append(np.mean(evaluation_iou))
        print(f"\nEpoch {epoch}/{epochs} loss {np.mean(train_loss):.5f} iou {np.mean(train_iou):.5f} evaluation_loss {np.mean(evaluation_loss):.5f} evaluation_iou {np.mean(evaluation_iou):.5f}")
    return hist
```

When I run:

```
model = UNet()
hist = fit(model, dataloader, epochs=50)
```

I keep getting the following output & error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/tmp/ipykernel_84346/4198189162.py in <module>
      1 model = UNet()
----> 2 hist = fit(model, dataloader, epochs=50)

~/tmp/ipykernel_84346/2960851020.py in fit(model, dataloader, epochs, lr)
     19             #print(y_hat.device, masks.device)
     20             #plt.imshow(np.unique(masks.cpu().numpy(), return_counts=True))
---> 21             loss = criterion(y_hat, masks)
     22             print('a lot of attributes')
     23             loss.backward()    #GRADIENT DECENT, adam optimizer

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py in __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    139       else:
    140         call_fn = tf.__internal__.autograph.tf_convert(self.call, tf.__internal__.autograph.control_status_ctx())
--> 141       losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    142       return losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    143           losses, sample_weight, reduction=self._get_reduction())

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/focal_loss/_binary_focal_loss.py in call(self, y_true, y_pred)
    394                                  pos_weight=self.pos_weight,
    395                                  from_logits=self.from_logits,
--> 396                                  label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)
    397 
    398 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/focal_loss/_binary_focal_loss.py in binary_focal_loss(y_true, y_pred, gamma, pos_weight, from_logits, label_smoothing)
    250     # Ensure predictions are a floating point tensor; converting labels to a
    251     # tensor will be done in the helper functions
--> 252     y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
    253     if not y_pred.dtype.is_floating:
    254         y_pred = tf.dtypes.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1429   """
   1430   return convert_to_tensor_v2(
-> 1431       value, dtype=dtype, dtype_hint=dtype_hint, name=name)
   1432 
   1433 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1439       name=name,
   1440       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1441       as_ref=False)
   1442 
   1443 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1564 
   1565     if ret is None:
-> 1566       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1567 
   1568     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    344                                          as_ref=False):
    345   _ = as_ref
--> 346   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    347 
    348 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    270   """
    271   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 272                         allow_broadcast=True)
    273 
    274 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    282         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 283     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    284 
    285   g = ops.get_default_graph()

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    306 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    307   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 308   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    309   if shape is None:
    310     return t

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 
    108 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    641             return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__array__, (self,), self, dtype=dtype)
    642         if dtype is None:
--> 643             return self.numpy()
    644         else:
    645             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

I have been stuck with this problem for 3 days and I cant seem to find a solution. Can someone please help me out?

The output, after changing device to cpu, has become:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/tmp/ipykernel_56578/1031642734.py in <module>
      1 model = UNet()
----> 2 hist = fit(model, dataloader, epochs=5)

~/tmp/ipykernel_56578/2559002388.py in fit(model, dataloader, epochs, lr)
     19             #print(y_hat.device, masks.device)
     20             #plt.imshow(np.unique(masks.cpu().numpy(), return_counts=True))
---> 21             loss = criterion(y_hat, masks)
     22             print('a lot of attributes')
     23             loss.backward()    #GRADIENT DECENT, adam optimizer

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py in __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    139       else:
    140         call_fn = tf.__internal__.autograph.tf_convert(self.call, tf.__internal__.autograph.control_status_ctx())
--> 141       losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    142       return losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    143           losses, sample_weight, reduction=self._get_reduction())

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/focal_loss/_binary_focal_loss.py in call(self, y_true, y_pred)
    394                                  pos_weight=self.pos_weight,
    395                                  from_logits=self.from_logits,
--> 396                                  label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)
    397 
    398 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/focal_loss/_binary_focal_loss.py in binary_focal_loss(y_true, y_pred, gamma, pos_weight, from_logits, label_smoothing)
    264         return _binary_focal_loss_from_probs(labels=y_true, p=y_pred,
    265                                              gamma=gamma, pos_weight=pos_weight,
--> 266                                              label_smoothing=label_smoothing)
    267 
    268 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/focal_loss/_binary_focal_loss.py in _binary_focal_loss_from_probs(labels, p, gamma, pos_weight, label_smoothing)
    556     # Combine loss terms
    557     if label_smoothing is None:
--> 558         labels = tf.dtypes.cast(labels, dtype=tf.bool)
    559         loss = tf.where(labels, pos_loss, neg_loss)
    560     else:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in cast(x, dtype, name)
    986       # allows some conversions that cast() can't do, e.g. casting numbers to
    987       # strings.
--> 988       x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, name="x")
    989       if x.dtype.base_dtype != base_type:
    990         x = gen_math_ops.cast(x, base_type, name=name)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1564 
   1565     if ret is None:
-> 1566       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1567 
   1568     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    344                                          as_ref=False):
    345   _ = as_ref
--> 346   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    347 
    348 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    270   """
    271   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 272                         allow_broadcast=True)
    273 
    274 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    282         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 283     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    284 
    285   g = ops.get_default_graph()

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    306 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    307   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 308   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    309   if shape is None:
    310     return t

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 
    108 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    641             return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__array__, (self,), self, dtype=dtype)
    642         if dtype is None:
--> 643             return self.numpy()
    644         else:
    645             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: Can you set the device to 'cpu' instead of 'cuda' and check the error? Does it give any error with CPU? Cuz it gives a better error description with CPU, compared to CUDA.

Comment: Why are you using a Tensorflow loss but your code is in PyTorch?

Comment: @Suraj S Jain. I have done so. The error is now:
```
RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.
```
I will post the entire error now as well.

Comment: @Ivan. I thought I could implement a Tensorflow loss into a PyTorch code. I have also posted another question in which I try to implement Focal Loss numerically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754975/runtimeerror-the-size-of-tensor-a-6-must-match-the-size-of-tensor-b-3-at-no